Generating function for composition of symplectomorphisms
Given two symplectomorphisms $T_1: (q_1, p_1):\longrightarrow (q_2, p_2)$ and
$T_2: (q_2, p_2):\longrightarrow (q_3, p_3)$ and corresponding generating functions  $F_1(q_1, q_2)$ and $F_2(q_2, q_3)$, what is the formula for the generating function $F(q_1, q_3)$ of
the composed symplectomorphism $T=T_2T_1:(q_1, p_1):\longrightarrow (q_3, p_3)$?

Firstly, there's no guarantee that composing two symplectic transformations with $q-q$ generating function will produce another symplectic transformation with a $q-q$ generating function (see below for an example), so some conditions need to be true for this to happen, which will emerge in the discussion below.
By definition of generating functions, $F_1$ satisfies
$$
p_1\cdot dq^1-p_2\cdot dq^2 = \nabla_{q^1}F_1\cdot dq^1 + \nabla_{q^2}F_1\cdot dq^2
$$
while $F_2$ satisfies
$$
p_2\cdot dq^2-p_3\cdot dq^3 = \nabla_{q^2}F_2\cdot dq^2 + \nabla_{q^3}F_2\cdot dq^3
$$
Adding these equations yields
$$
p_1\cdot dq^1 - p_3\cdot dq^3 = \nabla_{q^1}F_1\cdot dq^1 + \nabla_{q^2}(F_1+F_2)\cdot dq^2 + \nabla_{q^3}F_2\cdot dq^3
$$
Both sides here are considered as functions of general $q_1,q_2,q_3$. To produce a generating function of $T=T_2T_1$, we need to pick a function $q^2 = {q^2}^*(q^1,q^3)$ so that the middle term on the RHS vanishes. In other words, the equation $\nabla_{q^2}(F_1+F_2) = 0$ needs to have a well-defined solution ${q^2}^*(q^1,q^3)$. By the implicit function theorem, this will be possible (at least locally) if the Hessian of $q^2 \mapsto F_1(q^1,q^2)+F_2(q^2,q^3)$ is invertible for all $q^1,q^3$.
Assuming this is the case, the generating function for $T$ will be
$$
F(q^1,q^3) := F_1(q^1,{q^2}^*(q^1,q^3)) + F_2({q^2}^*(q^1,q^3),q^3).
$$
As an example of a case where this doesn't work, consider the generating functions $F_1(q^1,q^2) = q^1q^2$ and $F_2(q^2,q^3) = q^2q^3$ (where for simplicity I'm just considering two-dimensional phase spaces). The corresponding symplectomorphisms are
$$
T_1(q^1,p_1) = (p_1, -q^1), \quad T_2(q^2,p_2) = (p_2, -q^2), \quad T(q^1,p_1) = (-q^1,-p_1).
$$
The composition $T$ is not generated by a function of the form $F(q^1,q^3)$. The above proof fails since the Hessian of $q^2 \mapsto q^1q^2+q^2q^3$ is zero.
Edit: I'm realising that while the above gives necessary conditions for constructing the generating function of the composition, these conditions may not be sufficient. For example, consider
$$
F_1(q^1,q^2) = q^1(q^2)^2,\quad F_2(q^2,q^3) = (q^2)^2q^3
$$
which generate the symplectomorphisms
$$
T_1(q^1,p_1) = (\pm\sqrt{p_1}, \mp 2q^1\sqrt{p_1}),\quad T_2(q^2,p_2) = (p_2/(2q^2), - (q^2)^2).
$$
The composition is again $T(q^1,p_1) = (-q^1,-p_1)$. The construction above requires solving
$$
\nabla_{q^2}(F_1+F_2) = 2q^2(q^1+q^3) = 0 \ \forall q^1,q^3 \implies {q^2}^*(q^1,q^3) = 0
$$
and hence
$$
F(q^1,q^3) = F_1(q^1,0) + F_2(0,q^3) = 0,
$$
which isn't a proper generating function. So it seems there also needs to be some requirement that the constructed $F$ actually defines a transformation.

Nice answer. When I asked chatgpt, it suggested $F(q_1,q_3)=F_1(q_1,q_2)+F_2(q_2_q_3)$, where $q_2=q_2(q_1, q_3)$ is a minimizer of the sum above. I checked it for a pair of randomly chosen linear symplectic transformations and it was the case indeed. Of course, as you mentioned, it will not work universally, as, say identity transformation does not have qq generating function at all.

Glad it was helpful. I was surprised to hear ChatGPT could answer this, but I've just tried, and yes it does indeed.

Too long for a comment. I believe that there is a problem with your notations. Let us consider in the first place a symplectomorphism $T_1$ sending (sorry for the change of notations) $(x_1,\xi_1)$ to
$(x_2,\xi_2)$. A generating function $F_1$ for that symplectomorphism will satisfy
$$
T_1\bigl(\frac{\partial F_1}{\partial \xi_2}, \xi_2\bigr)=\bigl(
x_1,\frac{\partial F_1}{\partial x_1}\bigr),
$$
so that
$F_1$ is a function of $(x_1,\xi_2)$. Now if we go on and consider $T_2$
sending  $(x_2,\xi_2)$ to
$(x_3,\xi_3)$, a generating function of $T_2$ will be a function $F_2(x_2,\xi_3)$
such that
$$
T_2\bigl(\frac{\partial F_2}{\partial \xi_3}, \xi_3\bigr)=\bigl(
x_2,\frac{\partial F_2}{\partial x_2}\bigr).
$$
